# How do I delete rows in a data frame based on the value (date) in one of the columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of daily data. It has **500,000+** rows and **18 columns**. The 2nd column contains the date.

*For example, it goes from 7/1/2017 to the current date, chronologically.*

I pull the data every Monday and input it into R, but I only want data up until the most recent Friday.

I've set a variable equal to the most recent Friday's date (in the exact date format of the data):

```
library(lubridate)

LastFriday <- gsub("X", "", gsub("X0", "", format(
                                   Sys.Date() - wday(Sys.date()+1), "X%m/X%d/%Y)))
```

which returns `9/15/2017`

How do I delete all the rows in the data frame after the last row that contains last Friday's date?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, though I have not tested it

```
keep_index <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df[,2]), "X%m/X%d/%Y") <= as.POSIXct(LastFriday, format = "X%m/X%d/%Y")
mydf <- df[keep_index, ]
```